# Mutli line Grid in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any sample for multi line grid in MVC4. 
Actually I creating a Purchase order screen in which user can enter multiple products for Purchase order. so I want a grid to enter all details like product id,quantity,description,price for large products. please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is to use "Model" any time you need to reference your model in your View

Example:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
```

If your model happens to be a ViewModel, then you'd use Model.Property.